# What is the thing I am missing so that the shadow of my SearchDisplay.searchDisplayController is not going

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchdisplaycontroller

This is my code in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:110.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:110.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
```

This is what I want:

[image]

But this is what I am getting:

[image]

Can any one tell me what am I missing?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: where did you add `UISerachBarController`? is it in `UITableView` header?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes, It is.

Comment: @Tulon Is it cancel button disable?

Comment: Nope! As you can see the cancel button is in the picture above.

Comment: I am not able get you, Can you please describe little bit more? if posible.

Comment: I simply take `SearchDisplayController` at the top of `myTableView`. Then try to display it according to the above picture. The codes are also available in my post. I set all the thing in my `viewDidLoad`. The color is showing the `translucent` is not going up of my color. Though I set it to `NO`.